# querystring having Arabic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I need to call a asp.net page from Javascript with `queryString` having Arabic text,
but it shows me an error when goes online but works smoothly  on local server.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
        data: "arKeyword="+encodeURIComponent($("#txt_arKeywords").val(),
        success: function(data) {    
             diaL("Details Updated Successfully");                  
        
         },
          error: function(){
              diaL('Error Occurred');
          }
 });
```

**when Arabic value is small then it works smoothly.
The problem arises when Arabic text is in multiple lines.**

The error is:

> error: function(){ diaL('Error Occurred'); }

The `$("#txt_arKeywords").val()` shows:

> تمثيل خادم الحرمين الشريفين بالمنطقة التأكد من تحقيق سير العدالة في المنطقة العمل على حفظ الأمن والإستقرار في المنطقة العمل على كافة الخدمات لمواطني المنطقة بالتعاون والتنسيق مع الجهات الحكومية والمشاركة في مراحل التخطيط لكافة الخدمات التأكدمن كفاءة وفعالية الخدمات التي تقدم لمواطني المنطقة والعمل على تحسين وتطوير تقديم تلك الخدمات تلقي شكاوي وإستدعاءات المواطنين والنظر في أمورهم والعمل على تلبية مطالبهم وحل مشاكلهم

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: error block gets called

Comment: error: function(){
                  diaL('Error Occurred');
              }

Comment: Have you tried visiting the page that you are trying to call in your browser to see what happens?

Comment: can you show what is in $("#txt_arKeywords").val() ?

Comment: تمثيل خادم الحرمين الشريفين بالمنطقة التأكد من تحقيق سير العدالة في المنطقة العمل على حفظ الأمن والإستقرار في المنطقة العمل على كافة الخدمات لمواطني المنطقة بالتعاون والتنسيق مع الجهات الحكومية والمشاركة في مراحل التخطيط لكافة الخدمات التأكدمن كفاءة وفعالية الخدمات التي تقدم لمواطني المنطقة والعمل على تحسين وتطوير تقديم تلك الخدمات تلقي شكاوي وإستدعاءات المواطنين والنظر في أمورهم والعمل على تلبية مطالبهم وحل مشاكلهم

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is working on your local machine most likely the error has something to do with server configuration, so check the default encoding configuration on your online server and compare it with your local one (better to have it set to utf-8)
Another possible issue if your request is GET and not POST is the URI being too long after encoding the Arabic text when sending the GET AJAX request,
If these solutions did not work please specify the error message you're facing.

Comment: asp.net page not gets called  when arabic text is in multiple lines

Comment: query string valuy is below

Comment: arKeyword=تمثيل%20خادم%20الحرمين%20الشريفين%20بالمنطقة%20التأكد%20من%20تحقيق%20سير%20العدالة%20في%20المنطقة%20العمل%20على%20حفظ%20الأمن%20والإستقرار%20في%20المنطقة%20العمل%20على%20كافة%20الخدمات%20لمواطني%20المنطقة%20بالتعاون%20والتنسيق%20مع%20الجهات%20الحكومية%20والمشاركة%20في%20مراحل%20التخطيط%20لكافة%20الخدمات%20التأكدمن%20كفاءة%20وفعالية%20الخدمات%20التي%20تقدم%20لمواطني%20المنطقة%20والعمل%20على%20تحسين%20وتطوير%20تقديم%20تلك%20الخدمات%20تلقي%20شكاوي%20وإستدعاءات%20المواطنين%20والنظر%2لبية%20مطالبهم%20وحل%20مشاكلهم%20%20&&enKeyword=تمثيل%20خادم%20الحرمين%20الشريفين%20بالمنطقة%20التأكد

Comment: above was in url
and below is actual value
تمثيل خادم الحرمين الشريفين بالمنطقة التأكد من تحقيق سير العدالة في المنطقة العمل على حفظ الأمن والإستقرار في المنطقة العمل على كافة الخدمات لمواطني المنطقة بالتعاون والتنسيق مع الجهات الحكومية والمشاركة في مراحل التخطيط لكافة الخدمات التأكدمن كفاءة وفعالية الخدمات التي تقدم لمواطني المنطقة والعمل على تحسين وتطوير تقديم تلك الخدمات تلقي شكاوي وإستدعاءات المواطنين والنظر في أمورهم والعمل على تلبية مطالبهم وحل مشاكلهم

Comment: Again are you using POST or GET in your AJAX request? and if you use only few Arabic keywords in you asKeyword value does it work?

Comment: example (الشريفين بالمنطقة التأكد من تحقي)
this works

but the above arabic comment did't work

Comment: Okay then you have to use POST not GET for the AJAX request, most likely you are using GET now and when encoding the long Arabic text the GET URI is too long to be sent, using POST should fix that

Comment: POST method did't take any value when i call (url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx")